# How to optimize parameters in a specified range in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

A trainable parameter `p` initialized to 0.5:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.p = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.5))

    def forward(self, x):
        y = x * self.p
        return y

model = Model()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()
y = torch.tensor([0.1,0.2,0.3])
x = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3.])
model.train()
for i in range(3):
    pred = model(x)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = loss_func(pred, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I want to optimize `p` in a certain range. For example, the value of `p` must between 0.2 to 0.6 in each epoch.

Comment: Is this a toy example or your actual code? If it is the former, gradient descent may not be the go-to method. Right now it is only a linear regression that can be solved in closed form.

Comment: @tilman151, it is a toy example. I want to let the trainable parameter ```p``` always in a specific range such as [0.2, 0.6] during the training process

Comment: maybe you clip the parameter using [clip_grad_norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.html)

Comment: A mere gradient descent cannot solve that class of problems. You want to look for constrained optimization. If your condition is soft (meaning `p` can go out of the range but by the least possible amount), then you can try to add a penalty to your loss functions that is constraining `p` to stay in the range as much as possible

Comment: This is a kind of reparameterization trick. In the variational auto encoder, std is modeled after passing values to exp function which enforces nonnegativity without any gradient modification or additional regularizers. Likewise you can model p feeding to 0.2 + 0.4 * torch.sigmoid(p) or piece wise linear function you craft, where you can enjoy differentiabilty on the intended range.

Comment: @trialNerror Thanks, I think add penalty is what I need. I considered the loss function as $(pred-y)^2 + \max\{p-0.6,0\} + \min\{p-0.2,0\}$, but I don't think it's a good loss function. Is there a better loss function?

Comment: Well, the loss function is always tuned with respect to the problem you want to solve, which we do not know here. So it's hard to tell. It is indeed the kind of penalty I had in mind, though you can increase its slope with exponents, scaling factors and stuff like that. On the other hand, @hkyi 's idea is really worth considering